# How can I test a Trigger.io Android native module API with int parameter?

Tags: parameters, trigger.io, native-methods

I'm writing a native Android module for Trigger.io.  This method is defined in API.java.

```
public static void foo(final ForgeTask task, @ForgeParam("bar") final int bar) {
    System.out.println("foo called "+task.params);
    task.success();
}
```

When I run the inspector and enter `5` in the text box for `bar`, I see the following output.

> `Called "test_test.foo" with "{"bar":"5"}"`
>
> `Error for "test_test.foo" with "{"message":"Parameter 'bar' was of the wrong type, expected an int","type":"UNEXPECTED_FAILURE","subtype":null}"`

I get similar errors if `bar` is declared as `long` or `double`.  However, the analogous iOS API works fine.

How can I test this method in the Android inspector?

Edit: I'm using Trigger platform v2.1.7 (latest at time of writing).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like its sending 5 over as a string when your function is looking for an int..  If trigger is only going to send it over as as a string you may want to change int to string and cast the string to int after the fact. Not the best solution but I would think that would work if trigger.io does not give you the option to send things over as an int

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that an html text input contains a string, and that this string is never parsed to an int.

**Option 1**

You can fix **ForgeInspector/assets/src/js/inspector.js**. Change:

```
$('#_run').click(function () {
    var module = $('#_module').val();
    var method = $('#_method').val();
    var params = {};

    $('.api_input input').each(function (i, x) {
        params[$(x).attr('id')] = $(x).val();
    });

    $('#_output').prepend('<pre class="alert alert-info">Called "'+module+'.'+method+'" with "'+JSON.stringify(params, null, '')+'"</pre>');
    forge.internal.call(module+'.'+method, params, function () {
        $('#_output').prepend('<pre class="alert alert-success">Success for "'+module+'.'+method+'" with "'+JSON.stringify(arguments[0], null, '')+'"</pre>');
    }, function () {
        $('#_output').prepend('<pre class="alert alert-error">Error for "'+module+'.'+method+'" with "'+JSON.stringify(arguments[0], null, '')+'"</pre>');
    })
});
```

to

```
$('#_run').click(function () {
    var module = $('#_module').val();
    var method = $('#_method').val();
    var paramTypes = modules[module][method];
    var params = {};

    $('.api_input input').each(function (i, x) {
        switch (paramTypes[$(x).attr('id')].type) {
            case 'int': params[$(x).attr('id')] = parseInt($(x).val()); break;
            case 'long': params[$(x).attr('id')] = parseInt($(x).val()); break;
            case 'double': params[$(x).attr('id')] = parseFloat($(x).val()); break;
            default: params[$(x).attr('id')] = $(x).val();
        }
    });

    $('#_output').prepend('<pre class="alert alert-info">Called "'+module+'.'+method+'" with "'+JSON.stringify(params, null, '')+'"</pre>');
    forge.internal.call(module+'.'+method, params, function () {
        $('#_output').prepend('<pre class="alert alert-success">Success for "'+module+'.'+method+'" with "'+JSON.stringify(arguments[0], null, '')+'"</pre>');
    }, function () {
        $('#_output').prepend('<pre class="alert alert-error">Error for "'+module+'.'+method+'" with "'+JSON.stringify(arguments[0], null, '')+'"</pre>');
    })
});
```

This will convert the values to the correct types.

**Option 2**

You can also write an [automated or interactive test](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/testing.html) to test your API method.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have defined a parameterless method `foo5` that calls `foo`.

```
public static void foo5(final ForgeTask task) {
    API.foo(task, 5);
}
```